# 'She is gonna poppa your dom'

Tags: slang

'She is gonna poppa your dom'

It's from Shortland Street E6739 at 10:10.
I googled word by word.
I find nothing about 'poppa' used as a verb on google.
What does it mean?

Comment: Possibly an allusion to not liking something associated with pappadums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nonsensical phrases in this form are fairly common. The form is to take a word or phrase where each part sounds like it could be a word on Its own, split it into A and B, and write "He is going to A your B". Usually the word is somehow relevant to the situation,  so a mountain climber might be told "he is going to ice your pick".

Here the word is poppadom (which has several valid spellings), so presumably there is an Indian food connection.

The implied meaning is "She is going to do something bad to you ".